# Header navigation padding collapses when browser resized

Tags: css, menu, margin, padding

I'm trying to setup a simple header so that when the browser is re-sized the left/right padding keeps the header contents away from the edges of the window. This works OK for the left side but on the right side the padding seems to collapse and the content is partially obscured.

Here is my HTML:

```
<header id="header-container">
  <div class="header-table-wrap">
    <div class="header-table">
      <div class="nav-wrap header-table-cell cell1">
        <nav class="navigation">NAV CONTAINER</nav>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-wrap header-table-cell cell2">
        <nav class="navigation">NAV CONTAINER</nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {margin:0;}

.cell2 {text-align:right}
.header-table-wrap { background-color: orange; }
.header-table { background-color: yellow;}
.header-table-cell { background-color: #bbb; }

.header-table {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.header-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.nav-wrap { padding: 20px 0; }
```

I also have the header setup on codepen here: http://codepen.io/dgwyer/pen/ByWNYZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyMNQR)**

```
.header-table {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* add this (box-model)*/
}
```

for more info on `box-sizing` refer [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Just out of curiosity is it possible to do this without using the box-sizing rule?

Answer (score 0):

Set on header table  box-sizing: border-box;

**CSS**

```
.header-table {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/efxna938/)**